# pulling mysql data based on time period using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to pull all rows from table where time is within 1 week, 1 month or 1 year as specified by user.
This is my query:

```
$query=MYSQLI_QUERY($con, "SELECT * FROM `Customers` WHERE date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 $time")or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

This is the form:

```
<select name="time">
    <option>-select-</option>
    <option value=WEEK>week</option>
    <option value=MONTH>month</option>
    <option value =YEAR>year</option>
</select></td>
```

this is where I set value of $time:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $time = $_POST['time'];
```

issue is no matter what i specify, week or month or year its returning all items in database.
How can I get it to stop looking after the time expires that is specified?

Comment: _“where time is within 1 week”_ – so you mean all records that are _newer_ than one week? That would mean their date would be _greater_ than now minus one week. And btw., I hope you’re not using code this naive actually, because this is one big security hole.

Comment: A contributing factor could be the missing quotes in `value=WEEK>` and the others. You should (*always*) add them `value="WEEK">` and do the same for the rest and try it again. Plus, have a read here http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/between-date.php

Comment: I'm trying to pull records that are within the last week, the last month or the last year....so between april 25-may 1 if i specify 1 week, april 1 to may 1 if i select month etc.... Fred I attempted to add the "" to value but it still returned all rows in table....as far as security goes this is not for production or commercial use or even online use. its a learning assignment im attempting to complete. i understand the risks of injection.

Comment: Is there any `data` in your table that are submitted one month or one year later

Comment: Wouldn't you want that to be `> NOW() - INTERVAL 1 $time`.  Are you trying to pull all records within the last month, week, year?  Also have you echoed `$time` to see if it is set?

Comment: $time is set properly. i have modified records in database to have some 1 year old 1 week old and 1 month old. i have 17 rows in my database all within different time ranges for testing purposes.

Comment: jacob you were right > was my issue.  it is now pulling data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

query was incorrect should have been > instead of < Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```sql
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN date1 AND date2;
```